# How to use context.go() method for ShellRoute in Flutter/GoRouter

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-go-router, flutter-routes

I have a login page, and after login homepage basically. The homepage has `BottomNavigationBar`, like Instagram, and It's obvious that it's not `GoRoute`, instead of this it's `ShellRoute`. So, `ShellRoute` has a `key`, but it has not `path` parameter, and because of this I can not use `context`. go or push methods.

I supposed that `ShellRoute` has a `path` but it's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things to keep in mind while using `context.go()` from `ShellRoute` to `GoRoute`

1. Specify `parentNavigatorKey` prop in each `GoRoute`
2. Use `context.go()` to replace page , `context.push()` to push page to stack

##### Code Structure to follow:

```
final _parentKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _shellKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

|_ GoRoute
  |_ parentNavigatorKey = _parentKey    Specify key here
|_ ShellRoute
  |_ GoRoute                            // Needs Bottom Navigation                  
    |_ parentNavigatorKey = _shellKey   
  |_ GoRoute                            // Needs Bottom Navigation
    |_ parentNavigatorKey = _shellKey   
|_ GoRoute                              // Full Screen which doesn't need Bottom Navigation
  |_parentNavigatorKey = _parentKey
```

---

*Refer detailed code and explaination of bottom NavigationBar using `ShellRoute` and `GoRouter` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74996767/13431819)*

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [sample code here](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/shell_route.dart) , and after the GoRouter settings, you don't need the ShellRoute's path.
After login, you just context.go('YOUR BottomNavigationBar's FIRST PAGE').
In the sample code, just use context.go('/a') and everything will work well!

Answer (score 0):

You should

- give "initialLocation" parameter to your "GoRouter"
- give "routes" parameter to your "ShellRoute"

After doing these, you will understand why you don't need to add "path" parameter to your ShellRoute.

```
final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  initialLocation: '/home',
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    /// Application shell
    ShellRoute(
      navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget child) {
        return ScaffoldWithNavBar(child: child);
      },
      routes: <RouteBase>[
        /// The first screen after login.
        GoRoute(
          path: '/home',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return const HomeScreen();
          },
        ),
        /// Second screen on the navigation bar
        GoRoute(
          path: '/discover',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return const DiscoverScreen();
          },
          ///Post Detail Screen inside of Discover Screen
          routes: <RouteBase>[
            GoRoute(
              path: 'post_detail',
              parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
              builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                return const PostDetailScreen();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

You can use `context.go('/discover')` in your ScaffoldWithNavBar() widget, when user tap the one of the bottom navigation bar item.