# Go router: Use GoRoute and ShellRoute

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, routes

What is the best approach to handle routing with GoRoute and ShellRoute.

I have 3 screens.
Setting - show full screen
A - show with a Bottom Navigation (wrapped with Shelled Route)
B - show with a Bottom Navigation (wrapped with Shelled Route)

The only issue I encounter in this config is a missing back button when I go to Settings screen. How can I fix it?

```
final goRouter = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/a',
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  routes: [
    GoRoute( // = Do not show Bottom Navigation, just a full screen
      path: '/settings',
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
        child: SettingsPage(),
      ),
    ),
    ShellRoute( // ShellRoute = Show Bottom Navigation
      navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
      builder: (context, state, child) {
        return ScaffoldWithBottomNavigation(
          tabs: tabs,
          child: child,
        );
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute( 
          path: '/a',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
            child: HomeScreen(label: 'A', detailsPath: '/a/details'),
          ),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: 'details',
              builder: (context, state) => const DetailsScreen(label: 'A'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/b',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
            child: HomeScreen(label: 'B', detailsPath: '/b/details'),
          ),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: 'details',
              builder: (context, state) => const DetailsScreen(label: 'B'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

##### Present mistakes in the code.

1. Using of `context.go('/someRoute')` for pushing page to the stack
2. Not using the `parentNavigatorKey` prop of GoRoute.

##### Possible solutions:

1. Use `context.push('/someRoute')` to push the page to the stack, only then you can see the back button in the pushed page.
2. Use `parentNavigatorKey` property in each `route` and specify explicitly where the present `GoRoute` lies .

   - If page is child of `ShellRoute` : `parentNavigatorKey:_shellNavigatorKey`
   - If page is child of `MainRoute` : `parentNavigatorKey:_rootNavigatorKey`

---

##### Updated `settings` route:

```
GoRoute( 
      parentNavigatorKey:_rootNavigatorKey       Specify explicity that settings page lies in the Main Route 
      path: '/settings',
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
        child: SettingsPage(),
      ),
    ),
```

*Now you will get rid of the `bottomNavigationBar` which lies inside the `ShellRoute`.*

---

Refer detailed code and explaination of bottom NavigationBar using `ShellRoute` and `GoRouter` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74996767/13431819)

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. This solves all my issues. 
I have applied this to my code and I've achieved everything I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To have a back button there is 2 paths you can follow.

1. Using push instead of go:

If you use push the back button will take you back to the previous page.

2. Using go to a subroute so for your case settings page needs to be sub-route of another page, which may not be feasible if there are multiple paths user can access the settings.

So i would recommend using push when navigating to the settings page

Comment: This is a perfect answer. Thank you!

Comment: However, Setting screen appears together with Bottom Navigation Bar. As far I know it shouldn't as far as it is no longer a part of Shell Route.