# How do I get the bottom navbar to still appear even when i use navigator.push with fflutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to navigate to a new page while still having the bottom nav bar accessible.

my main.dart class is

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void onTapImplemented(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    const HomePage(),
    const AddActivity(),
    const Notifications(),
    const ProfilePage(),
  ];
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Social Event App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0), primary: Colors.black, secondary: Colors.white),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
       home: Scaffold(body: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex), 
        
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: '',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add_outlined),
                label: '',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                label: '',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: '',
              ),
            ],
            selectedItemColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
            unselectedItemColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 146, 138, 138),
            selectedFontSize: 0,
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
            onTap: onTapImplemented,
          ),
          
          
          
            )
            
    );

    
}
}
```

and how i'm using the navigator.push func

ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () {
Navigator.of(context).push(
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
),
);
},
child: const Text('Edit Profile'),
)

I tried following this [article](https://medium.com/@theboringdeveloper/common-bottom-navigation-bar-flutter-e3693305d2d) but i kept running into an error with the "routesettings.name". i'm really new to flutter so its a bit unfamiliar

Comment: reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628510/flutter-keep-bottomnavigationbar-when-push-to-new-screen-with-navigator)

Comment: You can use go_router package and declaring shellRoute and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74624449/8144311).